# Is a good habit to use a component A inside component B?

Tags: angular

I want to create an instance of the component A in the component B, but I do not know if this is a good habit in Angular or it is a complete mess.

- **Component A**: Modal to ask if you are sure about delete a file. Exists a ***showModal*** attribute in ts file which trigger the modal (two-way binding) if this flag is setting as true.
- **Component B**: Where the files are managed to delete. **If component A return true will be delete**.

Comment: That's the purpose of Angular : reusable components. For a modal, if I use it more than once, I would create a modal component with class properties, create a service, and every time I need to use the modal, call the service (set properties + show it) and subscribe on the response (yes/no in this case).

Comment: This could be the perfect solution due to is a generic modal and it will be used in other components for sure. @Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure you could do something like:

**component a**:

popup code will be here. when user click on button it will emit event to parent. 
create event emitter here or some other way to convey button click to component b.

**component b**:

on some button(delete) click popup will appear. when you get event from child component a then you can invoke function in which you can do file operation. Once you receive data from component a you can close popup in same function of event invoker.

**Or**

you can create service which will manage communication between reusable component a and other caller component(currently component b). You need to subscribe service field in 1 component and in second component invoke service function which will change the value of subscribed field in caller component.